# Nested for loop - model.id in parent for loop does not match model.id in nested for loop (django)

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to access data from a parent to a child via a foreign key.

**WHAT WORKS - the views**

The data in the child is not "ready to be used" and need to be processed, to be represented in a progress bar in %.

The data processing is handled in the views. When I print it on the console, it seems to work and stored into a variable `reward_positions`.

```
Reward positions = [(<Venue: Venue_name>, reward_points, reward_position_on_bar)]
```

So this part works.

The plan is therefore to access `reward_position_on_bar` by calling `{{reward_positions.2}}`

**WHAT DOESNT WORK - the template**

But something is not working to plan in the template.

The template renders the last `child_model` (thats rewardprogram) objects of the `last parent_id` (thats venue) irrespective of the actual `parent_id` processed in the for loop.

**TEST RESULT & WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS**

I think my problem lies in my nested forloop. The `parent_id` in the parent forloop does not match the '{{reward_position.0}}' in the nested forloop.

Doing a verification test, `{{key}}` should be equal to `{{reward_position.0}}` as they both go through the same parent forloop.

However, if `{{key}}` does change based on venue.id (parent forloop id), `{{reward_position.0}}` is stuck to the same id irrespective of the parent forloop id.

Can anyone seem what I am doing wrong?

**THE CODE**

**models**

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, blank=True)

class RewardProgram(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, null = True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="venuerewardprogram")
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="reward_title",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'points', null = True, blank=True, default=0)
```

**views**

```
def list_venues(request):
    venue_markers = Venue.objects.filter(venue_active=True)
    
    #Progress bar per venue
    
    bar_total_lenght = 100
    rewards_available_per_venue = 0
    reward_position_on_bar = 0
    venue_data = {}
    reward_positions = {}
    
    for venue in venue_markers:
        print(f'venue name ={venue}')
                
        #list all reward programs
        venue.reward_programs = venue.venuerewardprogram.all()
        reward_program_per_venue = venue.reward_programs
        
        #creates a list of reward points needed for each venue for each object
        reward_points_per_venue_test = []
        
        #appends the points to empty list from reward program from each venue
        for rewardprogram in reward_program_per_venue:
            reward_points_per_venue_test.append(rewardprogram.points)
        
        #sorts list in descending order
        reward_points_per_venue_test.sort(reverse=True)
        
        #set position of highest reward to 100 (100% of bar length)
        if reward_points_per_venue_test:
            highest_reward = reward_points_per_venue_test[0]

        if not reward_program_per_venue:
            pass
        else:    
            #counts reward program per venue
            rewards_available_per_venue = venue.reward_programs.count()
                    
            if rewards_available_per_venue == 0:
                pass
            else:   
                #position of reward on bar  
                reward_positions = []
                for rewardprogram in reward_program_per_venue:
                    #list all points needed per reward program objects
                    reward_points = rewardprogram.points
  
                    #position each reward on bar
                
                    reward_position_on_bar = reward_points/highest_reward
                    reward_positions.append((venue, reward_points, reward_position_on_bar))
                    #reward_positions[venue.id] = reward_position_on_bar
                reward_positions = reward_positions
                print(f'Reward positions = {reward_positions}')

    context = {'reward_positions':reward_positions,'venue_data':venue_data,'venue_markers':venue_markers}
    
    return render(request,'template.html',context)
```

**template**

```
            {%for venue in venue_markers%}
    
            {%for key, value in venue_data.items%}
            {%if key == venue.id%} #venue.id = 3
                                  {% for reward_position in reward_positions %}#test result
                                  {{reward_position.0.id}} # = id = 7 (thats not the good result)
{{key}} #id = 3 (thats the good result)
                                  {% endfor %}
                                  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: {{value}}%" aria-valuenow="{{value}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    
            {%endif%}
            {%endfor%}
       
            {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Matching in a template is a severe anti-pattern: you should do this in the view, likely it is also even simpler.

Comment: Is it possible to explain exactly *what* you aim to render. Currently that is not very clear: you determine the maximum and set this to 100, but if there are a lot of small rewards, that can result in a progress bar that is very large, and thus a lot larger than the 100... I would think that using the sum of the rewards makes more sense as denominator.

Comment: The goal is to place a number of steps on the progress bar. The location of each step is calculated an stored in reward_position.2. Because it seems boostrap progress bar's lenght are in %, each position are calculated in %. To achieve this, I used the highest points achievable (highest reward) and compare each reward against this point. (reward_points/highest_reward). This gives me a precentage which I can then use to position the step on the bar (against 100%). Is it clearer? (I am going to add this to the post, I should have done that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things, which makes the template very complex (which often will only introduce extra bugs), and makes it even quite slow because of an *N+1 problem* in the view.

```
def list_venues(request):
    venues = (
        Venue.objects.filter(venue_active=True)
        .annotate(
            total_points=Sum('venuerewardprogram__points'),
            rewards_available=Count('venuerewardprogram'),
        )
        .prefetch_related('venuerewardprogram')
    )
    for venue in venues:
        for rewardprogram in venue.venuerewardprogram.all():
            rewardprogram.position_on_bar = round(
                100 * rewardprogram.reward_points / venue.total_points
            )
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'venues': venues})
```

then in the template, we can render this as:

```
{%for venue in venues %}
  <h1>{{ venue.name }}</h1>
  {% for rewardprogram in venue.venuerewardprogram.all %}
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: {{ rewardprogram.position_on_bar }}%" aria-valuenow="{{ rewardprogram.position_on_bar }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

this will thus take the `.position_on_bar` attributes we added to the `rewardProgram`s that we prefetched for the `Venue`s.

Comment: I was worried writing my question someone will shorten my entire code with a few lines. I am going to work on you answer and confirm to you by the end of the day (for some reason something is not working yet, but I should be able to work on it). As usual, I am impressed.

Answer (score 1):

The context only contains the rewards of the last venue because you are overriding `reward_positions` in every loop.

```py
    reward_positions = {}
    
    for venue in venue_markers:
        ...
        if not reward_program_per_venue:
            pass
        else:    
            ...
            else:   
                #position of reward on bar  
                reward_positions = []  # !!! previous reward_positions are overwritten here !!!
                for rewardprogram in reward_program_per_venue:
                    ...
                    reward_positions.append((venue, reward_points, reward_position_on_bar))

    # reward_positions is the list from the last loop
    context = {'reward_positions':reward_positions,'venue_data':venue_data,'venue_markers':venue_markers}
    
    return render(request,'template.html',context)
```